# EpiServer startup slow

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, episerver

I'm developing on a big EpiServer site. When the site starts it takes several minutes and you can see what happens in the VS.NET diagnostic tools. There are a lot of database calls (2400+). E.g. netPageDefinitionGet, netPageDefinitionList.

From what I understand the results of this will be inserted into the EpiServer cache. The site performs well when started.

This isn't really a problem when running the site, it's a problem when developing. Since this delay happens every time a developer starts the debugger, this causes lot's of wait time for all developers..

Any suggestions? Is it possible to keep the cache e.g. out of process between debugging sessions?

Comment: Are they running local databases? Which Episerver version is it?

Comment: It's EpiServer 9 if I check the assembly. Development is done on local IIS with a remote development database.

Comment: I would check whether it's slow if you run a local database. That way you'll know whether it's a network/bandwidth issue or an actual app issue. Do you have an unusual (high) amount of content types?

Comment: I will try to move the database locally. I've checked sql profiler and EpiServer calls the database 2400 times on startup..

Comment: Number of content types = 360.. I don't know if that is high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

360 content types is fairly high, so it might be that model synchronization is taking a long time.

You could try setting **EnableModelSyncCommit** to **false** in config to see if that speeds things up.

Note however that content types will no longer automatically be updated when content types are changed in code.

Comment: This makes it better! From 2400 calls down to ~800 calls! I suppose the calls left are solution specific.. But, can you implement your own cache provider in EpiServer and use NCache, ScaleOutState Server, Velocity, Redis or something similar to be able to preserve cache between application restarts?

Comment: I know examples where the runtime cache is persisted to disk, but I also know that it can cause interesting challenges in load-balanced environments. :)